# Problems with apt-get on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm seeing the following issue on Ubuntu 14.04 when I run `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`:

```
    + sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gsfonts gsfonts-x11 libfontenc1 libxfont1 xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core
  ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho
  ttf-arphic-uming firefox firefox-2 iceweasel mozilla-firefox iceape-browser
  mozilla-browser epiphany-gecko epiphany-webkit epiphany-browser galeon
  midbrowser moblin-web-browser xulrunner xulrunner-1.9 konqueror
  chromium-browser midori google-chrome
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gsfonts gsfonts-x11 libfontenc1 libxfont1 oracle-java7-installer
  xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 167 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,234 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,845 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ precise/main oracle-java7-installer all 7u72+7u60arm-0~webupd8~2 [22.3 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main gsfonts all 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1 [3,374 kB]
```

I'm not sure why the package isn't downloading, and I'm not sure where to start with debugging the problem. Could anyone help out with figuring out the issue?

The gsfonts package is taking a really long time to download - like 20 minutes or more (and then I terminated it). Why would it take so long?

Comment: Can't see any errors or issues. Seems like a normal package installation.

Comment: It seems to be attempting to download that gsfonts package for a really long time though - like 20 minutes or more (and then I terminated it). Why would it take so long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the normal package installation.. Just let it download, it could be because the hosting server is busy addressing too many requests simultaneously because of which it is taking quite a lot of time.

More about this package here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gsfonts